# Enviar formulario a través de un toggle switch

Tags: php, html

Soy incapaz de crear un toggle switch que al activarlo, a través de un formulario por el método POST me envíe la información de si el checkbox está marcado o no, y en función de eso que aparezca de una forma u otra.

La parte del toggle switch sería esta:

```css
.switch {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 30px;
      height: 20px;
    }

    .switch input {display:none;}

    .slider_gold {
      position: absolute;
      cursor: pointer;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: #ccc;
      -webkit-transition: .4s;
      transition: .4s;
      border-radius: 40px;
    }

    .slider_gold:before {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      height: 16px;
      width: 16px;
      left: 2px;
      bottom: 2.7px;
      background-color: white;
      -webkit-transition: .4s;
      transition: .4s;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }

    input:checked + .slider_gold {
      background-color: #2196F3;
    }

    input:focus + .slider_gold {
      box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
    }

    input:checked + .slider_gold:before {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(10px);
      -ms-transform: translateX(10px);
      transform: translateX(10px);
    }

    /* Rounded sliders */
    .slider_gold.round {
      border-radius: 34px;
    }

    .slider_gold.round:before {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

```html
<div style="width:100%;max-width:600px;margin:auto;display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;justify-content:center;">
                        <p style="font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;">Desactivar precios para miembros Gold</p>
          
          <form name="formulario_gold" style="margin-left:5px;margin-right:5px;" action="" method="post">
            <!-- SI ES GOLD QUE TENGA EL CHECKBOX MARCADO -->
                            <input id="checkbox_gold" type="checkbox" name="seleccion_gold" onchange="submit()" checked="">
            
            <label for="checkbox_gold" class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <span class="slider_gold"></span>
            </label>
          </form>

        </div>
```

Y para recibir el formulario cada vez que haya un cambio uso `onchange="submit()"`. Si está activada me debería crear una coookie y si no lo está igual, pero no lo hace:

```
if (isset($_POST["formulario_gold"])) {
        $resultado = $_POST['seleccion_gold'];
        if ($resultado == "on") {
            setcookie('es_gold', "con_gold", time() + (86400 * 365), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
        } else {
            setcookie('es_gold', "sin_gold", time() + (86400 * 365), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
        }
    }
```

Comment: El formulario se envía? Si haces un `echo` de `$resultado` que te da?

Comment: @azeós sí, me devuelve `on`.